# How to set run as account for azure automation using ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I want to set run as account for an automation account. Is it possible to do it using ARM template ?
Thank you so much.

Comment: The recommended way is to use a `managed identity`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/enable-managed-identity-for-automation rather than a `run as` account. Probably something you would like to have a look ?

Comment: Please take a look at Jul_DW's workaround and Thomas' suggestions as well to see if they are helpful to you. If you think it is a solution, please mark it as a correct answer for others who meet the same question.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/quickstart-create-automation-account-template), creating the Run As Account from an ARM template is not supported (see the note). Only the Automation Account can be created.

What you can do instead - create a Powershell script that triggers the creation of the Automation Account using an ARM template first, and creates the Run As Account afterwards. See [Create an Azure Automation Run As Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/create-run-as-account#create-account-using-powershell).